# Converting NumPy array to a column vector

Tags: python, numpy

Subsetting a column of a DataFrame gives me the `y` (dependent) variable in form of a NumPy array.

`y = train['Survived']`

But printing the `.shape` of the variable `y` `(y.shape)` outputs `(891,)` (notice it's not `(891, 1)`, a column vector).

I would like to perform matrix multiplication of `y` with a variable with size (1 x 10) using [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), but it's throwing me this error:

`Exception: Dot product shape mismatch, (891,) vs (1, 10)`

How can I force the `y` variable to be a column vector with size `(891, 1)` instead of just `(891, )`?

Comment: just use `y=train['Survived'].values[:,None]`

Comment: or use `y=train['Survived'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: So the goal is (891,10) array?

Comment: `y = train[['Survived']]` will also have that column vector shape.  However that is quite a bit slower, since it makes a new dataframe (as opposed to extracting a series/column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `y[:,None]`. This will have the correct shape